# contract address field displays null in transaction receipt

Tags: solidity, blockchain, javascript

I have ran into an issue
this is my `deploy.js code` :

```js
const { ethers , run ,network} = require("hardhat");
async function main() {
  const simpleStorageFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("simplestorage");
  console.log("deploying contact ...");
  const simpleStorage = await simpleStorageFactory.deploy();
  await simpleStorage.waitForDeployment();
  console.log(
    "simple storage contract address is",
    await simpleStorage.getAddress()
  );
  if(network.config===11155111 && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY){
    await simpleStorage.deployTransaction.wait(1);
    await verify(simpleStorage.getAddress(),[]);
  }
  const transactionResponse = await simpleStorage.store("abhay", 50);
  const transactionreceipt=await transactionResponse.wait(5);
  console.log(transactionResponse);
  console.log(transactionreceipt);
  console.log(await simpleStorage.friend[0]);
}
async function verify(contractAddress,args)
{
  console.log("verifying contract ...");
  try{
  await run("verify:verify",{
    address:contractAddress,
    contructorArguments:args,
  })}
  catch(e){
    if(e.message.toLowerCase().includes("already verified")){
      console.log("Already Verified");
    } else {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
}
main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

and this is my `hardhat config file` :

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("dotenv").config();
//require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan");
const sepolia_rpc_url=process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL;
const private_key=process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
const etherscan_api_key=process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY;
/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  defaultNetwor:"hardhat",
  networks:{
    sepolia:{
      url:sepolia_rpc_url,
      accounts:[private_key],
      chainId:11155111,
      gasPrice: 30000000000,
    }
  },
  solidity: "0.8.24",
  etherscan:{
    api_key:etherscan_api_key
  }
};
```

and this is the command  I used to run the file  `yarn hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network sepolia` and this is the output I am getting :

```
 deploying contact ...
simple storage contract address is 0x991C443574228A925Cbd862e785dAB7B45ce36cb
```

```
ContractTransactionResponse {
  provider: HardhatEthersProvider {
    _hardhatProvider: LazyInitializationProviderAdapter {
      _providerFactory: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
      _emitter: [EventEmitter],
      _initializingPromise: [Promise],
      provider: [BackwardsCompatibilityProviderAdapter]
    },
    _networkName: 'sepolia',
    _blockListeners: [],
    _transactionHashListeners: Map(0) {},
    _eventListeners: [],
    _isHardhatNetworkCached: false,
    _transactionHashPollingInterval: undefined
  },
  blockNumber: null,
  blockHash: null,
  index: undefined,
  hash: '0x6209994a2462bff15325c2f0e57d33169a3e91e899cf4ccd60455cf726e537c2',
  type: 0,
  to: '0x991C443574228A925Cbd862e785dAB7B45ce36cb',
  from: '0x21aC6C585aC7C332Cac24A0658B344FB9456Bc15',
  nonce: 24,
  gasLimit: 113531n,
  gasPrice: 30000000000n,
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: null,
  maxFeePerGas: null,
  maxFeePerBlobGas: null,
  data: '0x781942790000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000056162686179000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  value: 0n,
  chainId: 11155111n,
  signature: Signature { r: "0xd9d6876f8ec7642f6358088f41323bd93931e1fba7404aba86e0f8fd430ba06d", s: "0x58193d5463d154d9541092d966922e8ed284e77890c541b18c4af5f39bf1e1b3", yParity: 0, networkV: 22310257 },
  accessList: null,
  blobVersionedHashes: null
}
```

```
ContractTransactionReceipt {
  provider: HardhatEthersProvider {
    _hardhatProvider: LazyInitializationProviderAdapter {
      _providerFactory: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
      _emitter: [EventEmitter],
      _initializingPromise: [Promise],
      provider: [BackwardsCompatibilityProviderAdapter]
    },
    _networkName: 'sepolia',
    _blockListeners: [],
    _transactionHashListeners: Map(0) {},
    _eventListeners: [],
    _isHardhatNetworkCached: false,
    _transactionHashPollingInterval: undefined
  },
  to: '0x991C443574228A925Cbd862e785dAB7B45ce36cb',
  from: '0x21aC6C585aC7C332Cac24A0658B344FB9456Bc15',
  contractAddress: null,
  hash: '0x6209994a2462bff15325c2f0e57d33169a3e91e899cf4ccd60455cf726e537c2',
  index: 0,
  blockHash: '0x3c14524884a975e98e2f645ef1cb375a5a93a41f26a9971eadfe6a3d48e0fa2d',
  blockNumber: 5435486,
  logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  gasUsed: 112502n,
  blobGasUsed: undefined,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 112502n,
  gasPrice: 30000000000n,
  blobGasPrice: undefined,
  type: 0,
  status: 1,
  root: undefined
}
```

```
undefined
```

This undefined should also be not there as I want the output as the array and also my smartContract file is fully compiled and is correct.
Etherscan at that particular address says no transaction
Can anybody please help me with this issue.

Edit:      after changing the `api_key` to `apiKey` and `defaultNetwor` to `defaultNetwork` in hardhat.config file ,I am now getting the follwing error :

````
                    ConnectTimeoutError: Connect Timeout Error
  at onConnectTimeout (/home/divyanshu/hh-fcc/hardhat/node_modules/undici/lib/core/connect.js:186:24)
  at /home/divyanshu/hh-fcc/hardhat/node_modules/undici/lib/core/connect.js:133:46
  at Immediate._onImmediate (/home/divyanshu/hh-fcc/hardhat/node_modules/undici/lib/core/connect.js:174:9)
  at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:478:21) {
code: 'UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.                    
```                                                                                                              Also when running on hardhat network it takes ifinite amount of time and does'nt show anything .
````

Answer (score 0):

The `contractAddress` in the `ContractTransactionReceipt` has only a value if the transaction is sent to the blockchain to deploy a contract. For a normal transaction you need to check the 'to' value, which is the contract address that receive the transaction (function store())

https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/providers/#TransactionReceipt-contractAddress